# Azure digital twin - counting the number of models

Tags: azure, azure-digital-twins

In the Azure Digital Twin (ADT) limitation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/reference-service-limits

there is a limitation on the "number of models within a single Azure Digital Twins instance".

My questions: how to count the number of models in ADT? what is counted as a single model in ADT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all the models by using the az CLI, there is a [model list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-iot/dt/model?view=azure-cli-lates&WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034t#ext_azure_iot_az_dt_model_list) command that you can use. Alternatively, you can use any of the SDKs to do the same. I get the number of models by adding a JMESPath query to it:

```sh
az dt model list -n <adt-name> --query "length(@)"
```

This will only return the number of models.

Comment: Considering the example about "planet" in 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/digital-twins/concepts-models

where we have "planet", "crater", and "moon", Could we say that we have 3 models here?

Could we say that the nummer of models is equal to the number of interfaces/entities/concepts?

Comment: In that example, you have 3 models. Every model is of @type 'interface' at this moment (DTDL V2).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What about the number of twins (also in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/reference-service-limits)? Is it based on the total number of instances of all interfaces?

For instance, in that example, if we have: "Jupiter" & "Earth" as the only instances of "planet" interface, and "callisto" & "ganimede" as the only instances of the "moon" interface, 

can we say that we have 4 twins?

Comment: Correct again, 4 twins. A twin is an instance of a model.
Feel free to mark my answer as accepted if it helped you!